# Creating NSMutableString from std::string in ObjC fails

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image: std::string stores expected value]

[image: cast to NSMutableString results in failure]

As you can see here, the std::string `font` has the correct value I would expect, now I want to assign that value to my `NSMutableString` parameter, but this cast to `NSMutableString` results in "unable to read data". I'm stumped....

Comment: Because you are breaked on that instruction, so it hasn't been set to `fontName` yet?

Comment: Could you show how you call `getFont:...` method?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.